# suggest the best way to write the code of bellow equation in latex

Tags: latex

I tried to write the code of this equation but there are some mistakes, I tried by many ways but could not find the right way, so please help me in this. My code is here.

```
$|\,\psi(t=0) \,\rangle=\left| \, \psi_{0}\right \rangle \, \stackrel{A: \lambda}{\longrightarrow},| \, \psi \lambda\rangle \, | \, \psi_\lambda \, \rangle \, \longrightarrow \, | \psi(t) \, \rangle = | \, \Tilde{\psi} \, \rangle \,\stackrel{A : \lambda_2}{\nearrow} \,\stackrel{A: \Tilde{\lambda} }{\longrightarrow} \, $
```

This is my output.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you make a *compilable* [mre]?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want something like this?

[image: ![According to example]

The full code, done with 'TikZ':

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) node{$|\psi_{t=0}\rangle=|\psi_{0}\rangle\stackrel{A:\lambda}{\longrightarrow}|\psi_\lambda\rangle\longrightarrow|\psi_t\rangle=|\Tilde{\psi}\rangle\stackrel{A: \Tilde{\lambda} }{\longrightarrow}|\psi_{\Tilde{\lambda}}\rangle$};
\draw[Round Cap-To] (2.25,1em) -- (2.8,2em) node[rotate=35,pos=.5,above,scale=0.7]{$A:\lambda_2$};
\draw (2.8,2em) node[anchor=west] {$|\psi_{\lambda_{2}}\rangle$};
\draw[-To] (0,-0.2) |- (0.5,-4em) node[anchor=west]{$|\psi_{t=\varepsilon}\rangle\stackrel{A:\lambda}{\longrightarrow}|\psi_\lambda\rangle$};
\draw[Round Cap-To] (2.25,-1em) -- (2.8,-2em) node[anchor=west] {$\dots$};
%\draw (0,-2em) node{$\longrightarrow$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: yes , thank you so much I want exactly like this.

Comment: If this answers your question, feel free to mark this as an answer by clicking on tick mark. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `stackengine` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{stackengine}

\begin{document}


\begin{equation}
  \stackMath
    A
  \stackengine{2pt}{
    \rightarrow B
  }{
    \rule[3pt]{.5pt}{1.5ex}\mkern-7mu\rightarrow
    C
  }{U}{l}{F}{T}{S}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]